# Does VARCHAR ever require more than two bytes of extra storage?

Tags: mysql

I've read through several other questions on here and in the [relevant mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) but haven't found a sufficient answer.

From the docs,

> A column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.

If I set VARCHAR(255), only one length byte is used. If I set VARCHAR(256), two length bytes are used. **What happens if I used VARCHAR(65535), the maximum size allowed by the datatype?** Are only two length bytes still used? Or is it higher now? If this is the case, where are the other transitions for the length byte sizes.

Comment: MEDIUMTEXT and MEDIUMBLOB need 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
2^16 = 65536
```

So 2 bytes is enough to store numbers up to 65535.